# Eye gouging noise

Tags: human, visuals

The sound of someone bursting someone's eyes out (like in game of thrones (spoilers)). Need something I can perform on stage. We tried the voice already, it didn't take so we need something easy and reliable.

Comment: More info please... not everyone has seen Game of Thrones. And what do you mean by 'perform on stage'? Does this affect the choice of prop/technique suitable?

Comment: yeah so there's a part where a big guy bursts the eyes of his oponent with his thumbs and it's like a really grisly popping/gushing noise. And this is something I have to perform live on stage so it can't be huge or layered or anything unweildy

Comment: Just learned the term is "performable". as in can be done live. I need performable eye gouging

Comment: Does it need to work more than twice?

Comment: it doesn't need to work more than twice, but it does have to HAVE TO work the first time I try it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For things like this I've used heavily cooked macaronis for the gooey sound in combination with messing around with a spoon in a jar of jam, and biting a special kind of big green grapes for the bursting of the eyes. Squeezing oranges, lemons and pomelos gives awesome squishy sounds as well. Mind you, the eye-sockets are hollows just like the mouth, there is pretty much you can do by forming it with your mouth. And jam tends to be a pretty pleasant thing to use for things like this no less ;-)

Then it's all up to choosing the right pieces, and the mixing of the components.

Comment: awesome, the cooked macaroni and spoon in jam is totally performable. I'm sure a grape would sound better but that's not as stage-friendly

Comment: A practical solution that comes with a free salad, what's not to like?

Answer (score 2):

alright what we went with was squeezing cooked spaghetti noodles in one hand that were soaked with water. It wasn't perfect but I think it got the idea of the effect across.